# Deployment failing using Google Cloud Build on to GCS

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-build

I have a reactjs static app running on Google Cloud Storage. Using Cloud Build, I'm trying to automate the build and deployment process.

Following is the cloudbuild.yaml file:

```
steps:
  # Install
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    entrypoint: 'npm'
    args: ['install']

  # Test
  #- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    #entrypoint: 'npm'
    #args: ['test', 'test:ci']

  # Build
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    entrypoint: 'npm'
    args: ['build']

  # Syncing to Static Hosting on GCS  
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
    args: ["-m", "rsync", "-r", "-c", "-d", "./build", "gs://mybucket.com"]
```

The last step which is Syncing to GCS is failing. I'm getting below error:

```
Starting Step #0
Step #0: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
Step #0: npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/package.json'
Step #0: npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
Step #0: npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/package.json'
Step #0: npm WARN workspace No description
Step #0: npm WARN workspace No repository field.
Step #0: npm WARN workspace No README data
Step #0: npm WARN workspace No license field.
Step #0: 
Step #0: up to date in 0.711s
Step #0: found 0 vulnerabilities
Step #0: 
Finished Step #0
Starting Step #1
Step #1: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
Finished Step #1
Starting Step #2
Step #2: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
Step #2: CommandException: arg (./build) does not name a directory, bucket, or bucket subdir.
Finished Step #2
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

My project structure:

```
RootProject
  -> front-end-webapp
           -> src/
           -> cloudbuild.yaml
           -> build/
           -> public/
           -> package.json
  -> backend-service1
  -> backend-service2
```

The trigger which I have written points to cloudbuild.yaml file inside the front-end-webapp sub-folder.
When I manually execute

```
npm run build or yarn build
```

then I get production ready files inside build folder under front-end-webapp which I want to put on Google Cloud Storage. Only files inside the build folder and not the build folder itself containing files.

I tried a lot but not able to get it. If I do . instead of './build' in the args like args: ["-m", "rsync", "-r", "-c", "-d", "./build", "gs://mybucket.com"] then cloud build executes successfully but it also copies entires files and sub-folders present in the root project.

Comment: Did you notice the output from step 0 that said it couldn't find a package.json?  I'm not convinced that your current directory is where you think it is.  Maybe include a test step that logs the current directory and a recursive listing of what is present from there.

Comment: how to log a directory...is there any environment variable I need to pass? Any sample code/syntax please?

Comment: Run a step that executes a shell that runs `pwd`.  A recursive listing using a shell step that runs `ls -laR` will probably help too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The build job is triggered by a file committed into the `front-end-webapp` and you run the `cloudbuild.yaml` file which is into `front-end-webapp`.

**BUT**, the root of the repo, is `/` and not `front-end-webapp`. Thereby, add the [`dir: 'front-end-webapp'` attribute on each step](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config). That force the steps to start into the correct folder!

**EDIT**

When I'm stuck and lost in the directory management, I introduce this step for having a view of what exist in my workspace.

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud:latest
  entrypoint: "ls"
  args: ["-lah","/workspace"]
```

Comment: thanks, dir is required here. I'm sorry but still getting error  'Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
CommandException: arg (./workspace/front-end-webapp/build) does not name a directory, bucket, or bucket subdir.' ......

Comment: - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
    dir: 'front-end-webapp'
    args: ["-m", "rsync", "-r", "-c", "-d", "./workspace/fe-web/build", "gs://dev.getsmallpdf.com"].   I tried ./fe-web/build and ./build but all in vein

Comment: I added a tip to help you in the debug.

Comment: you are amazing...I debugged and found a dot was causing the issue. I updated to this and it worked like a charm args: ["-m", "rsync", "-r", "-c", "-d", "/workspace/fe-web/build", "gs://dev.getsmallpdf.com"]

Comment: Happy to help! :)