# Deploy cloud function using cloud build

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

This my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.18.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

And this is my cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
#Install
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['install']
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bF7B1.png)

I am trying to deploy cloud functions using cloud build but I am not getting the hosting URL for my code.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you share your code? We can't see your function's type. There is not URL for event driven functions like Firestore triggers ,etc.

Comment: well it is just a simple hello world function.

const functions = require("firebase-functions");

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req,res) => {
  res.send("Hello World")
});

Comment: Please share the document you are referring to for this also add more details of your logical implementation for this, is this for emulator you are using.

Comment: Check this document https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#emulate-execution-of-your-functions  and   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72312392/best-way-to-edit-package-json-file-for-firebase-cloud-functions

Comment: Ujjwal, let me know if my recommendation were helpful, or are you looking for some other information.

Answer (score 0):

The cloud build log details show that there is a `npm WARN saveError ENOENT:no such file or directory, open ‘/workspace/package.json’` warning message.

The log also has a package-lock.json file to try eliminate this warnings and saveError delete package-lock.json file and then install packages,

`rm package-lock.json && npm install`

You can check a similar [Stackoverflow question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62246012/deployment-failing-using-google-cloud-build-on-to-gcs).